# Express.js server not working all of a sudden - Cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, html, express

My extremely simple express server using node.js suddenly stopped working. It was working fine (only testing it on my local machine for now), then I tried using browserify (which didn't work and I ended up deleting it) and when I went back to the site I was getting a Cannot GET / error.

I've tried uninstalling browserify, re-installing it, uninstalling and re-installing the two npm packages I'm using, even deleting all of my folders and starting from scratch (just pasting in the code on a couple of files). No matter what I still get the same error and I have no idea why. If I open index.html it still opens perfectly, while when I run my server (index.js) it doesn't throw any errors and seems to be listening as it's supposed to.

The server at the moment:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

My files are currently structured like this:

- public

  - assets (just has some images)
  - node_modules
  - index.html
  - index.js
  - package-lock.json
  - styles.css

Comment: You're not serving your `index.html`, you should move it under your `public` folder since that is where you set up your static route.

Comment: Sorry that was a formatting error, fixed it now - any other ideas?

Comment: @khan sorry I don't know what you mean, where is it supposed to be? It was working fine earlier without it though

Comment: yes both there and at http://127.0.0.1:3000 (saw that on a tutorial somewhere)

Comment: Where is your Express app file located in your directory?

Comment: in the node_modules folder i think? not entirely sure to be honest, how would I check?

Comment: You can post a picture of your directory tree if you're using a code editor like VSCode or Sublime. If you're not using a code editor, you can go click into your project directory and list all files/folders. I don't think it would be in your `node_modules` folder unless you moved it in there.

Comment: I installed Express with npm and never saw it appear anywhere, i can see there's a folder for it in node_modules although I'm not sure that's what you're referring to

Comment: Not related to your problem, but there should NOT be a `node_modules` in your `public` directory.  You don't want to offer public access to a code directory.

Comment: @Jul, sorry, I am referring to the file where your server code resides in. But long story short, `__dirname` is resolving to the wrong path, `index.html` is not being hosted, and Express is looking for `app.get('/', ...)`. Express does not find such route and throws `Cannot GET /`.

Comment: It's in the same folder as everything else, the public folder (public/index.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server's path is `/public/index.js`, `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` is resolving to `/Users/.../your_directory/public/public`. Express cannot find such a directory, so it proceeds down its pipeline. Since you did not define a GET `/` route, Express throws the error.

I would recommend removing your server file from `/public`.

Here's what your new directory tree would look like:

```
my_directory
    node_modules
    public
        assets
        index.html
        styles.css
    server
        server.js (index.js in your case)
```

After you set up your directory tree as such, you can change the following:

```
var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// becomes

var dir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');

// The '..' is used to move one directory level up.
```

Then, you should be able to see `index.html` when going to http://localhost:3000.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for your patience and for explaining some basic best practice, I'm pretty sure you can tell this is my first time doing this

Answer (score 3):

Your `index.html` file should be in `public` folder and then it will work. At the moment, you have set the static path to public folder which doesn't contain any file.

Comment: Sorry that's a formatting error, it is in the public folder